# Where do I find the metaball panel?

Tags: meta-objects

In the manual it says press <kbd>F9</kbd> but I have tried that, and it doesn't work. I am trying to find this for the negative feature that meta-balls have.

Answer (score 1):

When in edit mode open Metaball panel and scroll down to Active Element section.

[image]